# Getting 404 when hitting API URL from react to node in production

Tags: node.js, reactjs, frontend, port, backend

I have a backend for the frontend framework for my app. On local, I am able to hit API URL from React to Node, but when I am deploying my app to prod, it is throwing me 404. I am currently using `netlify` to deploy my changes and checking them. Below is the code I am using in local to hit the API,

React-

```
const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/fetchData');
```

Node-

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const axios = require('axios');

const port = 5000;
const app = express();

app.use(cors());

app.get('/fetchData', async (req, res) => {
  const apiResponse = await axios.get(
    'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
  );
  res.send(apiResponse.data);
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server is up');
});
```

While building this code for prod, I am removing `http://localhost:5000` from the URL on React side and hitting the endpoint like this,

```
const response = await fetch('/fetchData');
```

But I am getting 404, could someone help where I am going wrong and how to hit the URL properly?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that by using

```js
const response = await fetch('/fetchData');
```

You are requesting using the frontend domain/ip.
So if the frontend domain was example.com, you are trying to access https://example.com/fetchData, I'm guessing you need to access https://api.example.com/fetchData. I'd recommend using an axios instance to add the base URL once only.

Comment: How https://api.example.com/fetchData? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Vivekkumar Replace api.example.com with your actual backend url